# Creating density plots using coordinates in R

Tags: r, spatial, density-plot

Thank you in advance

I'm trying to create a density plot of farms, of which I have the co-ordinates for. I have farm long/lat coordinates which I have transformed into spatial data and plotted on a New Zealand map using the following code;

```
# Read in New Zealand shape file 
NZ <-readShapeLines("ESRI_Shapefile_2016_Digital_Boundaries_High_Def_Clipped/TA2016_HD_Clipped.shp")

# Change projection 
proj4string(NZ)<-CRS("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0.0 +lon_0=173.0 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1600000.0 +y_0=10000000.0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m")

# Plot map and point data 
plot(NZ)
points(Farm_points)
```

Is there an easy way in which I can turn this point data into density data and plot on the map?

I have tried counting the number of points in each polygon with the GISTools package and the following code;

```
counts <- poly.counts(Farms_points, NZ)
```

However I get the following error message;

```
Error in identical(spgeom1@proj4string, spgeom2@proj4string) : 
  trying to get slot "proj4string" from an object of a basic class ("matrix") with no slots
```

Any suggestions welcome...

Thank you

Comment: are you able to provide sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Without your data, we cannot test why it is not working, however, the error message is clear: if you want `poly.counts` to work, you need to transform your matrix `Farms_points` into `SpatialPoints`:

```
Farms_points_sp <- SpatialPoints(Farm_points, proj4string = proj4string(NZ))
counts <- poly.counts(Farms_points_sp, NZ)
```